# My query works, but I'm struggling to extend it by incorporating another table

Tags: mysql

So simple, yet so difficult.
I have a query that is working fine, but now I need to extend it further.

Currently, the query outputs user status updates to the website alongside other information, such as who wrote the status etc.

Now, I need to modify the code to not output a user status if that user has been blocked (if they appear in my tbl_blocking)

I'm completely stuck, and have spent the last however many hours on this.

**I need to say,**
"If tbl_blocking.user = :who AND tbl_blocking.blocking != :who, don't output that result"
*In other words, if the person logged in (:who) has blocked someone, don't show their status.*

```
    //Get status results
                $sql = "SELECT 

                tbl_status.id as statID, 
                tbl_status.from_user as statFROM, 
                tbl_status.status as statSTATUS, 
                tbl_status.deleted as statDEL, 
                tbl_status.date as statDATE,

                tbl_users.id as usrID, 
                tbl_users.name as usrNAME,
                tbl_users.location as usrLOCATION,
                tbl_users.postcode as usrPOSTCODE,

                tbl_blocking.id as blockID,
                tbl_blocking.user as blockUSER,
                tbl_blocking.blocking as blockBLOCKING,
                tbl_blocking.date as blockDATE,
                tbl_blocking.active as blockACTIVE,

                tbl_photos.profile as photosPROFILE,
                tbl_photos.photo_link as photoLINK,
                tbl_photos.default_photo as photoDEFAULT

                FROM tbl_status 

                LEFT JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_status.from_user = tbl_users.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_blocking ON tbl_status.from_user = tbl_users.id
                LEFT JOIN tbl_photos ON tbl_photos.profile = tbl_users.id 

                WHERE tbl_status.deleted = '0' AND (tbl_photos.default_photo IS NULL OR tbl_photos.default_photo = '1')
    AND (tbl_blocking.user = :who AND tbl_blocking.blocking !=who) OR IS NULL
                ORDER BY tbl_status.date desc

                    ";
```

Comment: And again I am wondering at the amazing skill, with which PHP users can create several screens of core right out of nowhere. </offtopic>

Comment: what are you talking about?

Comment: That's just random musings while looking at the only visible part of the query that fits into screen. You can make it useful, though. Apparently not all the query parts are essential for the question. By simplifying your query you can help others and even yourself to deal with it

Comment: If I was going there I wouldn't start here.

Comment: You can only block one user? Explain your schema.

Comment: No, many users can be blocked

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to use an `ON` clause like the following for `tbl_blocking` (which seems way off to start with):

```
LEFT JOIN tbl_blocking
  ON tbl_blocking.blocking = tbl_status.from_user
  AND tbl_blocking.user = :who
```

Then include the following WHERE clause:

```
 WHERE ....
    AND tbl_blocking.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Is it correct saying 'IS NULL' in place of what I had?